# addClass & removeClass not working

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle, addclass, removeclass

I have a menu, it should work as a click menu, so when clicking the button a menu will appear, and when clicking the button again, the menu should disapear, but i cant get it to work ?

I've got this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#dropdown').click(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#dropdown').attr("id", "dropdown2");
                $('#dropmenu').addClass("open");
                //$('#dropmenu').fadeIn('fast');
            },500);
        })
        $('#dropdown2').click(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#dropdown').attr("id", "dropdown");
                $('#dropmenu').removeClass("open");
                //$('#dropmenu').fadeIn('fast');
            },500);
        })
      });
    </script>
```

It works fint when adding the class, but then when im clicking the button again, it wont remove the class "open"

Comment: Why on earth are you changing the ID?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you write `$('#dropdown').attr("id", "dropdown2");`,  there is no `#dropdown` element for the code in the second handler to match.
Also, when you bind the second handler, there is no `#dropdown2` element yet.  (`live` events would solve that issue)

Instead, you should use the [`toggle` event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), which allows you to bind multiple `click` handlers that will execute every other click.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#dropdown').toggle(
        function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#dropdown').addClass("open")
                              .fadeIn('fast');
            }, 500);
        },
        function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#dropdown').removeClass("open")
                              .fadeOut('fast');
            }, 500);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: I've tried looking at the toggle() function, but cant quite seem to figure it out :s

Comment: Hmm, it doesnt add the class?

Comment: It should add the class.  Did you wait half a second?

Comment: Yeah, you can check it here: http://cabiweb.inforce.dk - If you click on "mere på cabiweb" it should add the class, but i doenst ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it isn't working is that the dropdown2 id doesn't exit when you register the click handler. You could use to live to overcome this, but it is better to use classes:

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#dropdown').click(function(){
        if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
          setTimeout(function(){
              $('#dropmenu').addClass("open");
             //$('#dropmenu').fadeIn('fast');
          },500);
       } else {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#dropmenu').removeClass("open");
            //$('#dropmenu').fadeIn('fast');
        },500);
      }
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated above code, working good for me. Please try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#loginlink").click(function(){
        $('.container .col-sm-6 ul li .dropdown-menu').first().toggle(
            function() {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.container .col-sm-6 ul li').first().addClass("open").fadeIn('fast');
                });
            }
        );
        if(("#loginformstarthere").length){ 
            $(".container .col-sm-6 ul li .dropdown-menu").first().append( "hello");
    }

});
```